# Interval time from MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, time, intervals

I need all rows from my table of MySQL database between the hours 06:00 AM and 08:00 AM.

I have launched this sql query without success because I don't understand the output.

The time interval ( 06:00 AM and 08:00 AM ) is incorrect, how to do resolve this ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
mysql> SELECT
    DAYOFWEEK(dStart) AS DOW,
    dStart,
    dEnd,
    cd
FROM
    `2019tblCd`
WHERE
    (
        cd IN ('P')
        AND DAYOFWEEK(dStart) BETWEEN 2
        AND 6
        AND (
            time(dStart) >= '06:00:00'
            OR time(dEnd) <= '08:00:00'
        )
    )
ORDER BY
    STR_TO_DATE(dStart, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') DESC
LIMIT 10;

+-----+---------------------+---------------------+----+
| DOW | dStart              | dEnd                | cd |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+----+
|   6 | 2019-06-07 19:15:41 | 2019-06-07 19:38:53 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 18:51:28 | 2019-06-07 19:17:47 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 18:29:39 | 2019-06-07 18:35:32 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 18:22:27 | 2019-06-07 18:45:33 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 18:09:07 | 2019-06-07 18:38:51 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 18:05:31 | 2019-06-07 18:42:46 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 17:48:01 | 2019-06-07 17:58:08 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 17:34:26 | 2019-06-07 18:23:23 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 17:26:54 | 2019-06-07 18:08:29 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 17:10:28 | 2019-06-07 17:48:48 | P  |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+----+
10 rows in set
```

**Edit #2**

```
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+----+
| DOW | dStart              | dEnd                | cd |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+----+
|   6 | 2019-06-07 07:15:41 | 2019-06-07 07:38:53 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 06:51:28 | 2019-06-07 07:17:47 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 06:29:39 | 2019-06-07 06:35:32 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 06:22:27 | 2019-06-07 06:45:33 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 06:09:07 | 2019-06-07 06:38:51 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 06:05:31 | 2019-06-07 06:42:46 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 05:48:01 | 2019-06-07 05:58:08 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 05:34:26 | 2019-06-07 06:23:23 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 05:26:54 | 2019-06-07 06:08:29 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 05:10:28 | 2019-06-07 05:48:48 | P  |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+----+
10 rows in set
```

**Edit #1**

The output correct is :

```
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+----+
| DOW | dStart              | dEnd                | cd |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+----+
|   6 | 2019-06-07 06:15:41 | 2019-06-07 07:38:53 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 06:51:28 | 2019-06-07 07:17:47 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 06:29:39 | 2019-06-07 07:35:32 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 06:22:27 | 2019-06-07 07:45:33 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 06:09:07 | 2019-06-07 07:38:51 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 07:05:31 | 2019-06-07 07:42:46 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 07:48:01 | 2019-06-07 07:58:08 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 07:34:26 | 2019-06-07 07:53:23 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 07:26:54 | 2019-06-07 07:58:29 | P  |
|   6 | 2019-06-07 07:10:28 | 2019-06-07 07:48:48 | P  |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+----+
```

Comment: => 6 **OR** <= 8?

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks but the output it's still wrong

Comment: You may have misinterpreted my comment. To be more direct: your problem description says "( 06:00 AM **and** 08:00 AM )", your code says "time(dStart) >= '06:00:00' **OR** time(dEnd) <= '08:00:00'". If that does not solve your problem, you may want to add what the correct output should be to clarify your problem (instead of just saying that your current output is incorrect, which is implied, as otherwise you would probably not ask here) .

Comment: @Solarflare I have edit my first question and I have  added the correct output. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :

```html
mysql> SELECT
    DAYOFWEEK(dStart) AS DOW,
    DATE_FORMAT(dStart,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') as dStart,
    DATE_FORMAT(dEnd,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') as dEnd,
    cd
FROM
    `2019tblCd`
WHERE
    (
        cd IN ('P')
        AND DAYOFWEEK(dStart) BETWEEN 2
        AND 6
        AND (
            DATE_FORMAT(time(dStart),'%H:%i:%s') >= '18:00:00'
            AND DATE_FORMAT(time(dEnd),'%H:%i:%s')  <= '20:00:00'
        )
    )
ORDER BY
    STR_TO_DATE(dStart, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Many thanks for reply, I have edit my first question and I have added your output **Edit #2**

Comment: If it's worked for you then please mark as right answer.

Comment: No, not working in the output I have `2019-06-07 05:10:28 | 2019-06-07 05:48:48`

Comment: Can you elaborate some more about your comment.

Comment: I need all rows from my table of MySQL database between the hours 06:00:00 and 08:00:00. Whit your query in output I have this wrong row `2019-06-07 05:10:28 | 2019-06-07 05:48:48`. Please see my **Edit #2** in my first question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194942/discussion-between-kishan-and-golia).